# What will intersects() return in this situation?

Tags: java, intersection, java-2d

There is a `Rectangle2D.Double` object named `rect2d` and a `Line2D.Double` object named `line2d`.

Please consider the following situation:

[image]

**Question 1:**

What will this line of code return?

```
boolean intersect = line2d.getBounds2D().intersects(rect2d);
```

**Question 2:**

The width/thickness of `line2d` **is 1 pixel**. It's height/length is 20 pixels.

**What would be the width and height values of the `Rectangle2D` object returned by `line2d.getBounds2D()`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return:

```
false
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=10.0,y=10.0,w=0.0,h=20.0]
```

With this code:

```
Line2D.Double line2d = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 10, 30);
Rectangle2D.Double rect2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100);

boolean intersect = line2d.getBounds2D().intersects(rect2d);
System.out.println(intersect);
System.out.println(line2d.getBounds2D());
```

Although, it's useless to say that a line is 1 pixel, because it can't be other way using `Line2D.Double`. 
Indeed, for Java, this vertical line as a 0-pixel width **boundary**, so that's why it will never intersect with any other shape. With a non-vertical and non-horizontal line, its **bounds** intersect.

Do not use bounds to compute intersection, but directly the Shape:

```
boolean intersect = line2d.intersects(rect2d);
```

You may check [RectangularShape.intersects()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#intersects%28java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29) Javadoc for more information on how this method computes intersection.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the reason that `line2d.getBounds2D().intersects(rect2d);` returns `false`? Is it because the line's bounding box has no width, or is it because the line's bounding box is inside `rect2d`, but not touching it's boundaries?

Comment: Because the line's bounding box has no width. I tried with a very long line that crosses the rectangle and it also returned `false`

Comment: And what if `rect2` of dimensions 20*20 is entirely inside `rect1`, not touching it's boundaries? What will rect1.intersects(rect2) return?

Comment: `true` because its bounds intersect the other rectangle

Comment: But I agree, the first example with the line is a bit weired, mathematically speaking.

Comment: And rect2.intersects(rect1) - will also return true?

Comment: Thing is that I'm not sure what they mean by 'bounds'. Only the border? Or the interior too?

Comment: I mean, if two shapes A and B share pixels inside of each other, but their borders do not touch. A is inside of B. Calling A.intersects(B) will return `true`, and so will `B.intersects(A)`?

Comment: Yes it's also returning `true` (I tested it)

Comment: The whole point here is that a 0-width shape (line or rectangle) will have 0-width bound, so it will never intersect with any other shape (reflexive)  (i have updated my answer to add this note)

Comment: Okay, so to make sure I understand: Whenever two shapes share pixels inside of them, or in their borders, they intersect. That means that if rect1 is entirely inside rect2, calling rect1.intersects(rect2) will return `true`, and calling rect2.intersects(rect1) returns `true` too. And if a shape has 0 width or height, it will never be 'intersecting' with anything as far as the intersects() method is concerned. Is all of this correct? (Thanks a lot for helping)

Comment: Yes that's it (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#getBounds2D%28%29 for a more formal definition)

Comment: Okay, so what do I need to do to check if a rectangle intersects with a line or if a line intersects with a rectangle?

Comment: Do not use Bounds but directly Shape.intersect: `line2d.intersects(rect2d)`  (sorry I removed my last comment as it was wrong)

Comment: Okay. Is there a possible situation where `shape1.intersects(shape2)` would return a different value than `shape2.intersects(shape1)`?

Comment: I don't think so. For intersection between a Rectangle and a Line, the source code shows it can never happen since `Rectangle.intersects(Line)` and `Line.intersects(Rectangle)` both use the same method `Rectangle.intersects(Line)`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersectsLine(java.awt.geom.Line2D)) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#getBounds%28%29), the first would return false and the second a bounding box at least the size of the dimensions of the line.

Comment: In this example, the method `Rectangle2D.intersectsLine()` is not used (but `intersects()`)